# Request for Acta Math Sinica 1984 paper

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, paper-request

The mathscinet reference for the paper I am after is here:

[MR807424](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=807424) 53C55 (32H99)
Chen, Zhi Hua; Yang, Hong Cang Estimation of the upper bound on the Levi form of the distance function on Hermitian manifolds and some of its applications. (Chinese) Acta Math. Sinica 27 (1984), no. 5, 631–643.

I looked up the specific edition on the journal webpage, which returns the following: https://www.actamath.com/Jwk_sxxb_cn/EN/volumn/volumn_1680.shtml (i.e., nothing).

Does anyone happen to know how to access this article? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The volume in question is available under the journal's webpage: [here](https://www.actamath.com/Jwk_sxxb_cn/CN/Y1984/V27/I5). The paper also has an [entry](https://www.actamath.com/Jwk_sxxb_cn/CN/10.12386/A19840058), but no PDF seems to be available. (These pages are in Chinese, so I might have missed something.) So you will need to go to a library where this issue is available, or obtain it through interlibrary loan.

Answer (score 3):

One can find it in CNKI (https://oversea.cnki.net/), which is a standard data base in China universities. The paper's url is
https://oversea.cnki.net/KCMS/detail/detail.aspx?dbcode=CJFD&dbname=CJFD7984&filename=SXXB198405006&uniplatform=OVERSEA&v=P71jx3wRsEP1PX1iGKBlljk3qqnnyEwVpNocJs_sA5T2lTuTkOnmhDjG5ofKYzT-

The paper is in Chinese. And there are two versions (pdf and caj)  of it. You can ask a frinds help you to get the ocr pdf version.